# Is there any alternate to Mirror modifier

Tags: mirror

Is there any alternate to Mirror modifier. I want to flip my model like a mirror but i do not want to use the mirror modifier. I have a model with 3-4 object and i want that complete model to be flip without joining. Later i have to use that for animation so i do not want to join them. How can i flip my complete model without using mirror modifier. Any other way or is there any addon

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is.
Select your object, go to Edit mode. Press <kbd>A</kbd> until everything is selected then press <kbd>S</kbd> (to scale). Type "-1" and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
The object will be mirrored and its location will be based on the [Pivot point](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/transform/transform_control/pivot_point/index.html).

Comment: Also don't forget to recalculate the normals after that (select everything in editmode and press ctrg + n) otherwise there might be artifacts in the render.